# Workspace Error type- 000301 for reconcile version

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

I have a arcpy script to reconcile and post edits from 1 child to 1 parent 9the parent is not the default version). 
my code:

```
import arcpy

print "Preparing to begin Water Version Reconile and POST..."

workspace = r"C:\Users\path\to\my\GDB.sde"
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
childVer = "sde.child_version"
parentVer = "sde.parent_version"
print 'Creating list of Database versions to work on...'

arcpy.ReconcileVersions_management(workspace, "BLOCKING_VERSIONS",     parentVer, childVer, "LOCK_ACQUIRED", "NO_ABORT", "BY_OBJECT",     "FAVOR_EDIT_VERSION", "POST", "KEEP_VERSION", "c:/temp/reconcilelog.txt")
```

And the error I receive:

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 16614, in ReconcileVersions
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000301: The workspace is of the wrong type
Failed to execute (ReconcileVersions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was causing my error.

The 2 versions I am working with (parent and child) were created by another user of the SDE(not admin).

This caused the version names to be formatted differently rather than the norm "sde.version_name".
In this case part of the version name is formatted as follows **"domain\username".version_name**
so since this is a string parameter you must enter it as: **`'"domain\username".version_name'`**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when attempting to use arcpy to run the [arcpy.ReconcileVersions_management geoprocessing tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/reconcile-versions.htm). The Esri sample script states `"SDE.Default"` for the Target Version parameter, but in order for the script to work I needed to capitalize the parameter as `"SDE.DEFAULT"`. The was the only change I needed to make in order for the process to complete successfully.